# Fatal error can't activate a plugin

Tags: plugins, fatal-error

I updated a plugin (elementor pro) and then tried to clear cache. The clearing process took forever, always see loading... so I close the browser tab.

Now if I go to my admin page I see this error:
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home3/santu2qw/public_html/informationmarketingexpert.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/share-buttons/module.php on line 144

I tried reinstalling the plugin but if I do I keep getting that message. I can't activate this plugin anymore.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If this is a 3rd party plug-in, then you will need to contact the author.

Comment: Looks like your php version is back-dated. Please update your php and then install the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

The plugin owner updated their plugin to solve issue...

Issue fixed.

Thanks

Comment: can we just close the question if the solution is based on outside our scope? Or perhaps even better delete the question? Nothing personal against the OP

Comment: I don't mind. :)